# python.manage.py runserver got many Importing xxx_ImagePlugin

Tags: django

After I update django version to 2.0 and begin to work with virtual environment when run the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

my log got many lines with info related Importing xxx_ImagePlugin. All work OK
but I do not understand why its appear each time and how to remove its from the log?

---

log:

```
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing BmpImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing BufrStubImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing CurImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing DcxImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing DdsImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing EpsImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing FitsStubImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing FliImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing FpxImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing FtexImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing GbrImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing GifImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing GribStubImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing Hdf5StubImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing IcnsImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing IcoImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing ImImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing ImtImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing IptcImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing JpegImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing Jpeg2KImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing McIdasImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing MicImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing MpegImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing MpoImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing MspImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing PalmImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing PcdImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing PcxImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing PdfImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing PixarImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing PngImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing PpmImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing PsdImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing SgiImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing SpiderImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing SunImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing TgaImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing TiffImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing WebPImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing WmfImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing XbmImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing XpmImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:49, Importing XVThumbImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing BmpImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing BufrStubImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing CurImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing DcxImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing DdsImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing EpsImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing FitsStubImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing FliImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing FpxImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing FtexImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing GbrImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing GifImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing GribStubImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing Hdf5StubImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing IcnsImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing IcoImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing ImImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing ImtImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing IptcImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing JpegImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing Jpeg2KImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing McIdasImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing MicImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing MpegImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing MpoImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing MspImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing PalmImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing PcdImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing PcxImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing PdfImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing PixarImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing PngImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing PpmImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing PsdImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing SgiImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing SpiderImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing SunImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing TgaImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing TiffImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing WebPImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing WmfImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing XbmImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing XpmImagePlugin
2017-12-27 09:05:51, Importing XVThumbImagePlugin
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the use in model.ImageField (demand pillow package). 
The pillow package is the reason for all this loggin.debug related images I got when run runserver.